# Are the flaps of a Cessna 414A fully extended at 15 degrees or at 45 degrees?

Tags: aerodynamics

When are the flaps of a [Cessna Chancellor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cessna_414) fully extended? At 45 or 15 degrees? Also, what are the range marks of its tachometer with Continental TSIO-520-NB engines?

Answer (score 6):

[image]

A Cessna 414A with the TSIO-520-NB is [listed here](http://www.cascadejets.com/1973_Cessna414_414-0461.htm), from a high-res [cockpit photo](http://www.cascadejets.com/images/1973_Cessna414_414-0461/Large/PNL/414-0461_InstPnl.JPG) both questions can be answered.

- The flaps extend to 45 degrees
- The TSIO-520-NB's red-line is 2700 RPM.

Comment: So flaps-full is 45 degs.

Answer (score 2):

Full flaps at 45°.  Normal range of the tach is 2100 to 2700 rpm.  TCM has since published a [service bulletin](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.tcmlink.com/pdf2/CSB09-11A.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjjp6_2pNnPAhVhwFQKHWb-ByIQFggbMAA&usg=AFQjCNEhYxbtt-SdHUftG8W_lDjBgymJAw) recommending no less than 2300 rpm in cruise due to issues with crankshaft counterweights.

The numbers on the face of the tach represent the first two digits of the rpm value.  When the needle points to "25" the rpm is 2500 rpm.  Each small mark between the numbers represents a value of 100 rpm.

Using ymb's image:

[image]

The other gauge (manifold pressure) has numbers hatched into the panel to designate maximum manifold pressure at high altitudes.  The "20" represents maximum available manifold pressure 20,000' (about 36"), for example.  As the plane climbs, the maximum possible power setting falls.  Those markings assume a well maintained turbo system, of course.

Comment: I assume the flap takeoff position is 15 degrees?

Comment: With the exception of the 404, I never used flaps for takeoff in any twin Cessna as standard practice. I would not want to lose one with the gear and 15° hanging out in a 414 carrying any kind of load..."yer gonna have a bad time." I believe all of the 300/400 twin Cessnas use draggy split flaps except the 404 and a handful of modified R/STOL 310s which use fowler/slotted-fowlers.

Comment: Follow up: I just flipped through the 421 normal procedures. It calls for flaps up on takeoff. I don't have a copy of 414 procedures handy but I'd be surprised if they were much different. I recall them being very similar.

Comment: Which 421 model? Early 400 series all used a simple split flap. Later versions like the 4141A and 421C used a more advanced type of flap.

Comment: I looked at a 421c manual. Manual indicates it's a basic split flap system (pg 7-15).  I'm interested to learn more, though.

Comment: I must have been thinking of the Robertson STOL fowler flap kits that were applied to some of these aircraft.

Comment: I did some digging after you responded.  I didn't know the R/STOL included 400 series twins.  I thought the 310 was the only option.  Cool stuff.

Comment: Are the KCAS numbers listed on the flaps control the stall speeds?

Comment: They are maximum speeds at which the flaps may be used.  Up to 160kts for 15° and up to 140kts for 30° and 45°.